# How to remove extra statistical mean results from JSON dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics

I'm working in python3 - I'm trying to determine the mean from measurements in a JSON dictionary of contaminants in a well. When I return the code its shows the mean of the data for each line. Essentially I want to find one mean for all results of one contaminant. There are multiple results for the same contaminant within each year.

```
for plants in data:

  for year in ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014":

  arsenic_values = []
  manganese_values = []

  all_year_data = data[plants][year]

    for measurement in all_year_data:
    if measurement['contaminent'] == "arsenic":

      arsenic_values.append(float(measurement["concentration"]))
      arsenic_mean = statistics.mean(arsenic_values)

        print(plants, year, arsenic_mean)
```

Here's an example of what the JSON looks like for 2 years.

```
  "well1": {
    "2010": [],
    "2011": [
      {
        "contaminent": "arsenic",
        "concentration": "0.0420000000"
      },
      {
        "contaminent": "arsenic",
        "concentration": "0.0200000000"
      },
      {
        "contaminent": "arsenic",
        "concentration": "0.0150000000"
      },
      {
        "contaminent": "arsenic",
        "concentration": "0.0320000000"
      },
      {
        "contaminent": "manganese",
        "concentration": "0.8700000000"
      },
      {
        "contaminent": "manganese",
        "concentration": "0.8400000000"
      }
    ],

Example of what it returns with my notes in ()

well1 2011 0.042
well1 2011 0.031   (this is the mean of the measurement before)
well1 2011 0.025666666666666667    (this is the mean of the measurement before and before that)    
well1 2011 0.0272    (**THIS IS WHAT I WANT** but I can't write like a counter function because the result I want is different for each well I am looking at.

IN summation:
There are multiple results for each year of the same containment and I want to find the average. But my code as it is written returns almost a triangular data that grows with each line. SO its finding's the average of each line for the containment rather than grouping all together and taking one average.
```

Comment: So, to be clear, you want one mean per contaminant for all wells and all years?

Comment: @gmds I would like one mean for each year for each well. As the code stands now (and in the example) it gives me 4 results for the year 2011 each one adding a number and creating a new mean each time.

Comment: There are a lot. That was just a snippet of the JSON file I have for 5 different sites each with a bunch of wells and each with a bunch of contaminants for years 2011-2010-2017.

Comment: not true @gmds you can just groupby containment without knowing all of them, and then you just have to iterate over every year

Comment: @aws_apprentice Yup, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate over the top-level keys and `groupby` the contaminent to achieve the desired result.

```
from statistics import mean
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

cnt = itemgetter('concentration')
cmt = itemgetter('contaminent')

d = {'well1': {'2010': [],
  '2011': [{'concentration': '0.0420000000', 'contaminent': 'arsenic'},
   {'concentration': '0.0200000000', 'contaminent': 'arsenic'},
   {'concentration': '0.0150000000', 'contaminent': 'arsenic'},
   {'concentration': '0.0320000000', 'contaminent': 'arsenic'},
   {'concentration': '0.8700000000', 'contaminent': 'manganese'},
   {'concentration': '0.8400000000', 'contaminent': 'manganese'}]}}

top_level = d.keys()
for key in top_level:
    for year, value in d.get(key).items():
        if not value:
            print('The year {} has no values to compute'.format(year))
        else:
            for k, v in groupby(sorted(value, key=cmt), key=cmt):
                mean_ = mean(map(float, map(cnt, v)))
                print('{} {} {} {}'.format(key, year, k, mean_))

The year 2010 has no values to compute
well1 2011 arsenic 0.02725
well1 2011 manganese 0.855
```

Links to some concepts that are used that you might not be familiar with:

[map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

[itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

[groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Comment: Thanks! Because the original JSON is much larger I tried to tweak it to work but it was giving me my original error message from a previous attempt of "string indices must be integers."

Comment: without showing the traceback I can’t really help, so post that

Comment: also exactly how are you modifying this code? that could be part of the problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of measures, you should avoid `itertools.groupby` since it needs a sorted list and sorting is expensive. It's easy to build a dictionary with the values grouped by `well`, `year` and `contaminent` using [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
>>> import json
>>> data_by_year_by_well = json.loads(text)
>>> d = {}
>>> for w, data_by_year in data_by_year_by_well.items():
...     for y, data in data_by_year.items():
...         for item in data:
...             d.setdefault(w, {}).setdefault(y, {}).setdefault(item['contaminent'], []).append(float(item['concentration']))
...
>>> d
{'well1': {'2011': {'arsenic': [0.042, 0.02, 0.015, 0.032], 'manganese': [0.87, 0.84]}}}
```

Now, compute the mean (or the median, or any aggregate value):

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> {w: {y: {c: mean(v) for c, v in v_by_c.items()} for y, v_by_c in d_by_y.items()} for w, d_by_y in d.items()}
{'well1': {'2011': {'arsenic': 0.02725, 'manganese': 0.855}}}
```